# Oracle queries acting strange why this is happening? Am i doing something wrong?

Tags: oracle, select

First sorry if i have a bad english:

1. `select * from table2 where column1='000022071001';`
   Returns nothing!
2. `select * from table1 where column1 not in (select column1 from table2);`
   Returns nothing
3. `select * from table1  where column1='000022071001';`
   IT RETURN VALUES!

This aint logical, if column1 value '000022071001' from table1 is not in table2 , why the second query returns nothing?

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What are the data types for the fields you are querying on?

Comment: shouldn't #2 be `in` instead of `not in` to get the same result as 3?  I believe the not is confusing you.  2 SHOULD BE `select * from table1 where column1 in (select column1 from table2)`; to get the same results as #3  ... 1) t2 has "A" in col1 ... no
2) get from t1 where not (return "A" from t2) no non-a records 
3) T1 HAS "A" yES!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be some NULL values in the column1 in the table2 causing this issue

Try this

```
 select * from table1 where column1 not in 
(select column1 
 from table2 
 WHERE column1 is not null)
```

Comment: Thanks i cant believe in that, my problem is solved, but why this happen?

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini, NOT IN returns no rows where any value is NULL